# How to set up multiple aliased joins between two models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In a Rails 3.2 app I need to set up two associations between the same two models.

For example

```
class User
  has_many :events
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :attended_events, through: :attendances
end

class Event
  belongs_to :event_organizer, class_name: "User"
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :attendees, through: :attendances, class_name: "User"
end

class Attendance
  belongs_to :attended_event, class_name: "Event"
  belongs_to :attendee, class_name: "User"
end
```

This is the first time I've experimented with aliasing class names, and I'm having trouble getting it to work. I'm not sure if the issue lies with how I've defined the associations, or elsewhere.

Do my associations look OK? Have I overlooked something needed to get this to work?

The problem I'm having is that no user ids are being set in the Attendance model. This may be a stupid question, but given my associations above, should the field name be :user_id or :event_organizer_id?

Really appreciate any suggestions on this. Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? What are you calling on these models?

Comment: I'm trying to create an event in the console. When I check the associated attendances that are created, user_id is nil.

Comment: I'm calling `Event.create(attendee_ids: [1,3,4], event_organizer: 1)`. Thinking about it now, I should probably have `attendee_id` on the Attendance model, rather than user_id, shouldn't I?

Comment: I'm not sure, check you class name method, the docs tell me it should be in this format ":class_name => 'Comment'" http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Yes, the model with the belongs_to gets the foreign key, you can also specify foreign key on a table with the :foreign_key methods.

Comment: please follow has_many rules - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foreign_key to be specified in User and Event

```
class User
  has_many :events

  has_many :attendances, foreign_key: :attendee_id
  has_many :attended_events, through: :attendances
end

class Event
  belongs_to :event_organizer, class_name: "User" 
  # here it should be event_organizer_id

  has_many :attendances, foreign_key: :attended_event_id
  has_many :attendees, through: :attendances
end

class Attendance
  belongs_to :attended_event, class_name: "Event" 
  # this should have attended_event_id

  belongs_to :attendee, class_name: "User"        
  # this should have attendee_id because of 1st param to belongs_to here is "attendee"
  # and same should be added as foreign_key in User model
  # same follows for Event too
end
```

Comment: thats great! thanks for helping clarify this, I was getting confused! One question, is it necessary to define `:class_name => "Event"` on `has_many :attended_events'?

Comment: try to understand why `:class_name` is required, 1st parameter is `attended_events`, so it looks for model `AttendedEvent` which you do not have, and there you meant `Event`, thats why it is necessary. All these mentioned at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html If you follow all default conventions then you just need to pass single param to these has_many, belongs_to. The moment you add aliases, you will need to tell original table names and foreign keys thats all it is

Comment: thanks @Amoi, I think I understand that. In my case I don't have a model named AttendedEvents, so I thought a `:class_name` would need to be defined. Your example above does not define this though (class User, has_many :attended_events). I'm trying to understand why?

Comment: its pretty simply man see docs => ":class_name
Specify the class name of the association. Use it only if that name can’t be inferred from the association name. So belongs_to :author will by default be linked to the Author class, but if the real class name is Person, you’ll have to specify it with this option." Finally its all naming convention game. In your case User has_many :attendances, there exist Attendance, so no need to define :class_name, but attendances table has attendee_id(and not user_id, because you wanted it as attendee) so need to define foreign_key

Comment: the only need( or primary) to define User has_many :attendances is that you need to use then this ":attendances" on the next line as through. You may not call @user.attendances.

Comment: "Use it only if that name can’t be inferred from the association name." OK, in my case `:attended_events` cannot be inferred from the association name. So I'd appreciate if you could please explain why I don't need `class User has_many :attended_events, through: :attendances, :class_name "Events" end`. Sorry if I'm being slow, but I'm trying to understand your example, which does not define the class_name here.

Comment: in simple words, 

when you use :through, it understood as there exists a middle model/table/association through which this association needs to be formed. 
In case of :through, the other options :class_name, :primary_key and :foreign_key are ignored.

Now it is important that through model should have been already associated. In above case you asked, you have through "attendances", and then there must exist direct association between User and attendances which is there. 

That means "User has_many :attendees, through: :attendances" without "User has_many :attendances" will fail

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12188/discussion-between-amol-pujari-and-andy-harvey)