# rails association has_many_and_belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have got two models, User and Event. I need two kind of relationship between User and Event.

- User (:as organizer) <-------> Event, many to many relationship
- User (:as attendee)  <-------> Event, many to many relationship

I am guessing if two different has_many_and_belongs_to association with polymorphism can be used to implement the relations. I am new to rails so I would appreciate any help regarding the problem.

Comment: Can one user be an organizer at the same time s(he) is an attendee? If this is not the case I don't think you need a polymorphic association

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not need a polymorphic relationship for this.

To define two associations between two models, you can do something like:

```
class User 
  has_many :organized_events, foreign_key: :organizer_id, class_name: "Event"
  has_many :attended_events, foreign_key: :attendee_id, class_name: "Event"
end

class Event
  belongs_to :organizer, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :attendee, class_name: "User"
end
```

This will give you a one to many relationship.

If you need many to many, you'll need a join table for each association.

```
class User
  has_many :attendances, foreign_key: :attendee_id
  has_many :attended_events, through: :attendances
end

class Event
  has_many :attendances, foreign_key: :attended_event_id
  has_many :attendees, through: :attendances
end

class Attendance
  belongs_to :attended_event, class_name: "Event" 
  belongs_to :attendee, class_name: "User"        
end
```

And something similar for the event organizer association.

See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898602/how-to-set-up-multiple-aliased-joins-between-two-models)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment you only need a polymorphic association if your relationships organizer and attendee can exist at the same time for the same user. If this is the case use a polymorphic association, if not you can use a `has_many :through` association or a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association. The first one is more flexibel though, as you have an additional model which can hold validations for example.